# issue implementing a map into HTML file using leaflet CSS and JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I am working on my assignment and I was wondering if you can point out the mistake that I am committing in my code.

For this assignment, I am building a map with a third-party library and API.

The steps were to:

1. Request an access token from Mapbox (Links to an external site.)
2. Generate an HTML 5 document.
3. Reference the leaflet CSS and JavaScript files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" h..t@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>

<script s..t@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
```

4. Set the map view to the following coordinates: Latitude: 39.678121 Longitude: -104.961753.
5. Add a zoom level of 15.
6. Add a tile layer and apply a max zoom of 20.
7. Add a marker using the provided coordinates.

So far, this is what I have:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Basic map</title>
 <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.js'></script>
 <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css">
 </head>
<body>
 <div id="map"></div>
 <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* required styles */

body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
} 

html, body, #map {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
       L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmVkYnVsbDg0IiwiYSI6ImNrZGNvYm9qeDB6cW0ycW16MmF0Y2szbW0ifQ.Fru8Yiy4GdL66v3o7769zg';
       var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
        .setView([39.678121, -104.961753], 15)
        .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));

       // L.marker is a low-level marker constructor in Leaflet.
       L.marker([39.678121, -104.961753], {
        icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-size': 'large',
          'marker-symbol': 'college',
          'marker-color': '#fa0'
        })
       }).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{S}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                   maxZoom: 20,
                   attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
       }).addTo(map);
```

For some reason, the HTML file will not load ( blank page) using the following in the head section of the HTML document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" h..t@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>

<script s..t@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
```

However, I was able to get the HTML file to load using the following links in the head section of the HTML document:

```
 <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.js'></script>

 <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Can you please assist with correcting this issue and other issue that you may have spotted?

Comment: Any errors on your [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)? And BTW it seems that you're missing some characters there in the `<link>` and `<script>` tags, did you copy-paste a version with ellipsis?

Answer (score 0):

Your link & script tags are missing href & src attributes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="h..t@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>

<script src="s..t@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
```

If it still doesn't work let us know where you got this path from:

```
"h..t@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
```

Comment: Those *should* come from https://leafletjs.com/download.html

Comment: I couldn't find the `h..t@1.6.0/dist` part in the download page.

Comment: I got the link from: https://leafletjs.com/download.html